# Chat media url gets expired after few minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-chat

I have created a chat web application using Twilio. It display chat messages(includes media files) in the webpage. So, Once I load the channel and display the channel media messages(fetches URL of media file using `getContentTemporaryUrl` function). So, after a few minutes it gets expired and If we click on it says "`Access denied`" message.

Is there any way to get the new URL of the message media file using message `sid`?
OR how can I know that the when the URL will expire based on the URL parameter or query string?

If I refresh the page/ Channel it works again. But, I don't want to reload the whole page again.

Comment: Got a solution?

Comment: nope. so, we did a work around was reload the whole page again after 5min.